# Can install Lubuntu 13.10 but can't 12.04 on Lifebook C1320D

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

I need Lubuntu 12.04 LTS on Fujitsu Siemens Lifebook C1320D but can't install. I can get first screen to choose language and then either choose Try... or Install... system stuck after one minute (no running dots). If I monitor prompt screen (ctrl+alt+f1) there are no error messages, just Welcome to 12.04 and couple more lines of info and stuck. I can do only reset after.

I tried with F6 and "nomodeset" off but no luck.

With 13.10 everything is smooth.

What can I do? Is there option to boot Live 13.10 and then via USB stick or CD (I have second USB DVD-RW and can attach) install 12.04 LTS?

Any other ideas?
I can't boot via USB stick (no option in BIOS), only DVD-RW

Comment: Try the alternate install iso which is a text-based installer. If you get any errors or other problems, please report back.

Comment: if, you can't boot from usb then i think the problem is with the BIOS version or something... i haven't seen any BIOS that can

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first place Lubuntu 12.04 has reached End of Life which means that you will get no more security patches or updates for the Lubuntu portion of the version.  Updates to the core (Ubuntu 12.04) will of course still be available.  Recommend you download and install Lubuntu 14.04 which is a Long Term Support version.
2. Your computer is more than likely recognizing the USB flash drive as another hard drive so when you boot, choose F2 or whatever key will get you to your BIOS.  Then navigate to boot and down to hard drive.  You may see a + sign by the hard drive.  Choose it and see if your flash drive is included there.  If it is move it to the top.  Save, close, and continue with the boot.

Comment: 1. That's true but Twinkle VoIP client is not supported by 14.04 and this laptop is for Call centre where only Twinkle is important. No other stable VoIP client alternative so I have to be sticked to 12.04 and Twinkle combination. 2. I know that but no USB option in Boot order, only HDD, DVD and Floppy. Laptop is more than 9 years old. Thanks, anyway.